# How to check a string in a list of files and display the latest modified one in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, count, grep

I'm searching for a particular pattern of string (which is a five digit number), in a list of files inside a particular directory.

Please note that the string is not fixed, and could be any combination of a 5-digit number.

I need to check if the string occurs in multiple files, then display only the latest modified file.

For example: a string "`73458`" occurs in multiple files, so it should display only the last modified file.

I can only grep the strings, not sure how to proceed with this.

```
grep -l "<BILL_UID>[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]</BILL_UID>" *_MOVE
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
grep -l "<BILL_UID>[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]</BILL_UID>" *_MOVE |
xargs -i ls -l --time-style=long-iso "{}" |
sort -k6,7 | tail -n 1
```

Edit:
OK, so I think I'm beginning to understand, but w/o proper sample data I find it hard to work with the info; is this more like what you expected?

```
grep -o "<BILL_UID>[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]</BILL_UID>" *_MOVE |
sort -u |
while read string ;do
    grep -l $string |
    xargs -i ls -l --time-style=long-iso "{}" |
    sort -k6,7 |
    tail -n 1
done
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need to display the last modified file of all the duplicate entries.Suppose the string '76535' is in two files: say, abc.txt and bcd.txt, so i need to display the last modified one among the two files.

Comment: yes, the output displayed only one file, there are 450 files in my current directory, so among 450 files,there could be two or more files which may contain multiple string like this :`[0-9]0-9]0-9][0-9][0-9]`. I need to display only the last modified one for each multiple string found. I hope i'm clear now :)

Comment: No, you're not. I assumed - given your initial question - that you're after a certain number.  From your unhappy but vague responses I gather that that's not the case?

Comment: Sorry for being not clear. Actually It's not a certain number that i'm searching. It could be any number of 5 digits.

Comment: [You should not use `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and the `read` should be `read -r`

Answer (score 0):

Traverse the files from newest to oldest, return the first match.

```
stat --format '%y %n' *_MOVE |
sort -r |
cut -c37- |
xargs grep -l '<BILL_UID>[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]</BILL_UID>' |
head -n 1
```

The `stat` call is not portable, but on my Linux, it produces lines like

```
2016-10-05 15:20:02.000000000 +0300 1onefile
2018-08-07 12:43:24.000000000 +0300 2another
```

which can be sorted lexically to order them by modification time, then we discard the timestamps we used for sorting and retain just the file names.

(This will fail if a file name contains a newline.  There are workarounds but unless you genuinely need to cope with that complication, let's just mention it.)

The entire pipeline exits when `head` exits so this should avoid scanning old files needlessly (though a few extra files will realistically have been scanned in parallel when the pipeline gets shut down).